# Kitchen Faucet shuts off both Hot and cold water whenever I try to use both

Tags: repair

Kitchen faucet was replaced...now it wont allow both Hot and Cold mix to flow together always shuts off.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info to tell you, but it sounds like whoever replaced the faucet made a mistake. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Will it work on both full hot only and full cold only?

Answer (score 1):

Look at and read the instruction sheet that is usually in the box with the new faucet. If it is a cartridge type , the cartridge may be installed in reverse or backwards.